# How to find index of the <tr> that has an element with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So as you can see in the image I'm trying to find the index of the `tr` when the green or red buttons are clicked. The red has `class = "cancel"` and the green has `class = "confirm"`

```
$(document).on('click', '.cancel', function() {
  var index = $("tr").find(this).index();
  $('.renglon').eq(index).html(antes[index]) check[index] = true
});
```

[image]

I was trying with

```
var index = $("tr").find(this)
```

as the code below which it does find the `<tr>` but cant get its index

I tried

```
var index = $("tr").find(this).index() //output = 0;  
var index = $("tr").find(this).index("tr"); //output = -1
```

In that line I am expecting `3` since the table header is also a `tr`

Answer (score 0):

`$("tr").find(this)` is the same as just `$(this)` (assuming `this` is contained inside a `tr`, so you're getting the index of `this`, not the index of the `tr`.

The `tr` that contains `this` is `$(this).closest("tr")`. So it's index is `$(this).closest("tr").index()`.